# List Elements in Python

Tags: python

```
def calculate_z_scores(raw_data):
    z_scores = []
    for i in raw_data:
        z_score = raw_data.element - (sum(raw_data) / len(raw_data)) / raw_data.stdev
        append.z_scores(z_score)
    return z_scores
```

This is the current code I have and I'm trying to use a loop to iterate through the `raw_data` list. I'm trying to calculate the Z-score for the current list element using the following formula:

```
("current element" -"average of " raw_data)/("standard deviation of " raw_data)
```

And the append the calculated Z-score to the `z_scores` list. But when I run it it says:

> List has no attribute to element.

I've never really worked with element so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. What is `raw_data`? If you are getting an error message, post the full message here. Help us help you.

Comment: `raw_data.element` should be `i`. But also, you should use a list comprehension for this rather than a loop. And if you can, numpy is an even more natural solution.

Comment: What are you expecting `raw_data.element` to be? The error message is correct. Python `list` objects don't have an `element` attribute.

Comment: That is not the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

when itterating though a list, the iterating item *is* the current element, so you would want to replace `raw_data.element` with `i`

Also, you need your own method for calculating standars deviation, or use an existing one like there's one in NumPy. Python lists don't have builtin stddev methods.

Then,

```
append.z_scores(z_score)
```

should have been

```
z_scores.append(z_score)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import statistics
def calculate_z_scores(raw_data):
    z_scores = []
    for elem in raw_data:
        z_score = (elem - (sum(raw_data) / len(raw_data))) / statistics.pstdev(raw_data)
        z_scores.append(z_score)
    return z_scores
```

or use a list comprehension:

```
import statistics
def calculate_z_scores(raw_data):
    average = sum(raw_data)/len(raw_data)
    std = statistics.pstdev(raw_data)
    return [(elem - average)/std for elem in raw_data]
```

or better still, use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
def calculate_z_scores(raw_data):
    data = np.array(raw_data)
    return list((data - np.mean(data))/np.std(data)) # Although I have a feeling you're better off leaving it as a numpy array
```

Comment: @iBug - Please be more specific. Also, have you tired running it after the edits?

Comment: why bring up `numpy` at all? The OP is obviously a beginner trying to learn how to program. Using `numpy` here is like using a cannon to kill a fly

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga if OP is working with data (and calculating z-scores strongly implies this), numpy is without a doubt going to be the fastest, cleanest solution. And I would say easier to learn and understand than using loops or list comprehensions.